# Posting JSON object using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, jackson

I wondered if someone could answer a question for me as I dont quite understand why I needed to read a json object from the request input stream when I passed one to a spring controller manually.

Normally I use a json-rpc framework and it handles everything for me so I hadnt actually had to do this manually until now. Everything works ok but what I dont understand is why there was nothing in the request like when you post a form, and instead I had to use this code to map my object to Jackson:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream());
ChartParameters chartParameters = mapper.readValue(bis, ChartParameters.class);
```

I would just like to understand why I needed to read in the input stream and pass this to jackson instead of being able to get a value as a string which I first thought I would have to do.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your Spring controller where those two lines are being used? A bit of context might clarify...

Comment: I wasnt really that interested in the Spring side of things unless the reason is purely spring related? I didnt write a plain servlet to test if I still needed to do the same thing. Here is the controller method anyway in case it is: public void handleChartJsonRPC(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {        
        jsonService.getBarChart(request, response);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a recent Spring version, the following should be enough to get things rolling:

```
@ResponseBody
public Chart handleChartJsonRPC(@RequestBody ChartParameters chartParameters) throws Exception {
    return jsonService.getBarChart(chartParameters);
}
```

This (obviously) assumes your `jsonService` returns a `Chart` object, which should be serialised to JSON before sending it back to the browser.

Make sure you have a MessageConverter that will (de-)serialise your objects to and from JSON, as described by @user2054820.

Comment: Right ok so is the reason that I had to get the stream because I dont have a message converter in the chain?

Comment: Most likely that's the reason, but it's a bit hard to say with only two lines of code context.

Comment: Ok thanks, for now I will have to assume thats the correct answer, and thanks for the code snippet above. I was planning to convert my chart object that the service returns manually with Jackson and then return this in the response but using a message converter and the annotations method looks a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can post your JSON just as a string and you can configure :

```
    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
      </list>
 </property>
 </bean>
```